# Inconsistent accessibility problem

Tags: c#, datacontext

I am following Rob Conery MVC Storefront tutorial series and I get an Inconsistent accessibility error from the following constructor public SqlCatalogRepository(DB dataContext) :

```
public class SqlCatalogRepository : ICatalogRepository
{
    DB db;

    public SqlCatalogRepository()
    {
        db = new DB();
        //turn off change tracking
        db.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
    }


    public SqlCatalogRepository(DB dataContext)
    {
        //override the current context
        //with the one passed in
        db = dataContext;
    }
```

Here is the error message :
Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'SqlRepository.DB' is less accessible than method 'Data.SqlCatalogRepository.SqlCatalogRepository(SqlRepository.DB)'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `DB` class is not public, so you can't make a `public` method (or constructor) that takes it as a parameter.  (What would callers outside your assembly do?)

You need to either make the `DB` class `public` or make the `SqlCatalogRepository` class (or its constructor) `internal`.

Which one you do will depend where your types are being used.
If the `SqlCatalogRepository` is only meant to be used inside your assembly, you should make it `internal`.  (`internal` means that it's only visible to other types in the same assembly)

If it's meant to be exposed by your assembly to other assemblies, you should make the class `public` but the constructor `internal`.

If the `DB` class itself is meant to be used by types outside your assembly, you should make the `DB` class itself `public`.

Answer (score 4):

The type `DB` is used in a public constructor of a public type. Therefore, the type `DB` must itself be public.

Answer (score 2):

Check the accessor on the DB class (you dont show it here) it would need to be a Public class in oreder to allow it to be passed in to the overloaded constructor.